# OS crahes when using read/write locks

Tags: c, unix, process, scheduling, freebsd

OS : FreeBSD 8.2 on Oracle VM Virtual Box

I am trying to test that a process attempting to acquire a read lock will be blocked until it is able to acquire it. After initializing `rw_lock` in Process #1 and locking the lock as a writer I create a second process which attempts to acquire the lock as a reader using blocking `rw_rlock()`. What I am shooting for is for process #2 to be blocked until process #1 releases Write lock so I am attempting to use pause to insure that process #2 has enough time to be scheduled. However this same pause somehow crashes the system in this scenario since if it is removed the program runs fine. If I replace the pause with a busy loop in Process #1, Process #2 does not get scheduled until Process #1 finishes so it ruins the point of the test. `DELAY()` also does not allow Process #2 to be scheduled. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Process #1:

```
static void test_rw_rlock(void)
{ 
    const int seconds = 1;
    rw_init(pResourceLock, "RWLock");
    rw_wlock(pResourceLock);
    kproc_create(&use_rw_rlock, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, "use_rw_rlock()");
    pause("---", hz * seconds);
    rw_wunlock(pResourceLock);
    rw_destroy(pResourceLock);
}
```

Process #2 :

```
static void use_rw_rlock(void* arg)
{
    rw_rlock(pResourceLock);
    rw_unlock(pResourceLock);
    kproc_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Are semaphores out of consideration?  (POSIX or Sys V)

Comment: I have to use rwlock since code that I am working with uses it

Comment: just a thought, if you `fork()` before entering lock code and pause, do u still get crash?

Comment: are you sure your processes share the same address space?

Comment: @TJD: From the man page of kproc "The new process shares its address space with process 0, the swapper process, and runs in kernel mode only." so they should share the address space. And if I increment a variable in new process the change is reflected in previous one.

Comment: @Ankush if you mean moving kproc_create() to the line after constant declaration then yes it is still crashing when I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleeping while hold a rw lock is a no-no.

Comment: Is there a way to allow process#2 to execute while process #1 holds the rw lock without sleeping?

Comment: You have two problems with your code: kproc_create as well as pause can/will sleep. Generally a better way is to obtain a lock in the new process once the process has been started. However it might be helpful if you actually describe what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to implement the same functionality of FreeBSD rwlock in vxWorks so the whole point of this is to verify that behavior of rwlock wrapper in vxWorks is still the same. That is why I want process #2 to attempt to acquire a lock that is being held by process #1

Comment: To synchronize the start it would be best to use semaphore and then use rw lock to actually test it. Process 1 (driving process) gets rw lock and then posts the semaphore. the other process tries to get the semaphore first and then the rw lock.